# Asp.net Profile Not Saving or displaying entered data (Code Updated) 10/28/12

Tags: asp.net, sql, profile, profile-provider

Asp.net profile is either not displaying or saving the data the user enters, However there is No Errors. here is a view of the code below: the webproject just Runs and nothing is displayed on both firstname amd lastname label.

This is A  WEB PROJECT ,,, I opened the project using OPEN WEBSITE!

HOWEVER the Project  Displays it as "WEBPROJECT.sln(3)" at the program title bar of VISUAL STUDIOS.

This is when the user creates the account and saves the users profile settings: ***NEW AND UPDATED***

```
protected void CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create an empty Profile for the newly created user
    ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(RegisterUser.UserName, true);

    // Save profile - must be done since we explicitly created it

    TextBox txtNewFirstName = (TextBox)RegisterUser.FindControl("txtNewFirstName");
    Profile.FirstName = txtNewFirstName.Text;


    TextBox txtNewLastName = (TextBox)RegisterUser.FindControl("txtNewLastName");
    Profile.LastName = txtNewLastName.Text;


    p.Save();
}
```

And this is when its is displayed: ***NEW AND UPDATED***

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
            ProfileCommon p = this.Profile.GetProfile(this.User.Identity.Name);

            Label firstName = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("firstName");
           Profile.FirstName = firstName.Text;


            Label lastName = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("lastName");
           Profile.LastName = lastName.Text;


    } 
}
```

And this is the Web config: ***NEW AND UPDATED***

```
 <profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" enabled="true">
  <properties>
    <add name="FirstName" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    <add name="LastName" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    <add name="Gender" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    <add name="BirthDate" type="DateTime" serializeAs="String"/>
    <add name="Occupation" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    <add name="Website" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    <group name="Forum">
      <add name="Posts" type="Int32" defaultValue="0"/>
      <add name="AvatarUrl" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
      <add name="Signature" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    </group>
    <group name="Address">
      <add name="Street" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
      <add name="PostalCode" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
      <add name="City" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
      <add name="State" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
      <add name="Country" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    </group>
    <group name="Contacts">
      <add name="Phone" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
      <add name="Fax" type="String" serializeAs="String"/>
    </group>
  </properties>

  <providers>
 <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
```

This is Whats being displayed on the aspnet_Profile on my sql server:

**[PropertyNames]**

[LastName:S:0:0:FirstName:S:0:0:]

This is redone of the previous code so please ignore previous comments below!

I have also Tryed **PreRender Method**:

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            ProfileCommon p = this.Profile.GetProfile(this.User.Identity.Name);

            Label firstName = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("firstName");
           Profile.FirstName = firstName.Text;


            Label lastName = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("lastName");
           Profile.LastName = lastName.Text;

}
```

But i get a error:  **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** for *Profile.FirstName = firstName.Text;*

Comment: ASP.NET Website Project or Web Application Project?

Comment: Yes. Very few people will attempt to answer your questions with 0%.

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication? And why are you assigning the profile to a label in three different methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it by removing all properties from Web.Config except for the first and last name properties. Try to narrow it down.

The following works for me. Although I set anonymousIdentification to true for convenience, I've given you the full syntax for a working membership Web.Config entry:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
        connectionString="Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=MYPCNAME;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="System.String" allowAnonymous="true"/>
        <add name="LastName" type="System.String" allowAnonymous="true"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="50000000"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
            enablePasswordReset="true" 
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
            requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
            passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
            passwordFormat="Hashed" 
            minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
            minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters="0" 
            passwordStrengthReqularExpression="0" 
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
            applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(fnTxt.Text 
            + lnTxt.Text, true);
        Profile.FirstName = fnTxt.Text;
        Profile.LastName = lnTxt.Text;

        p.Save();
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = Profile.FirstName + " " + Profile.LastName;
    }
```

Comment: I have changed it FROM PAGELOAD TO PRERENDER like you siad And i now receive an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for  Profile.FirstName = firstName.Text;

Comment: Try re-creating the project again from scratch to try and identify what you're missing?

Comment: I created the project from sractch and Still getting the same results. i think it might be something with the Web.Config ,Profile?

Comment: Are you certain it is a Web Site project and not a Web Application Project? When you open it, do you select a folder or a project/solution file?

Comment: When i open The Web project i select Project FOLDER then Load it.

Comment: I'll try and re-recreate this for you tonight (Pacific time), ok?

Comment: Alright i'll wait,And thank you, (btw im Eastern Time Zone, USA)